# AnyLogic Simulation NullPointerException during Descrete event execution on version 8.7.2&8.7.0

Tags: anylogic

I have a project which is running successfully on AnyLogic PLE 8.5.2 but failing on 8.7.0 e 8.7.2, giving me the following error:
Exception during discrete event execution:

```
NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.PedExtension.f(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.bn.a(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.bn.a(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.bo.c(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.bo.b(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.PedSettings.u(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.PedSettings.executeActionOf(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.EventTimeout.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.f(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.jf(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.h(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$e.run(Unknown Source)
```

is there any way to understand what is a problem and how to fix it? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Looks like some problem with a PedSettings object. Maybe try to delete that and see if it works

Comment: I don't use it for simulation. I use only: Ped Source, Ped To Go, Ped Wait, select output and Sink. I don't think i can delete it from the libraries...

Comment: correct. In that case, you must do the hard work and peel back features until it works. Also worth check the update notes to see what might cause the change.